# Order by in SQL in human readable format

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have some IP addresses in mySql database. I want to sort them via SQL ORDER BY, in ascending mode. but SQL sorts them in machine-readable mode, and I want to sort in human-readable.

It arranges my IP like this:

```
91.99.102.209
91.99.102.213
91.99.102.233
91.99.102.33
91.99.102.37
91.99.102.53
91.99.102.69
91.99.102.9
```

But I want to be sort like bellow:

```
91.99.102.9
91.99.102.33
91.99.102.37
91.99.102.53
91.99.102.69
91.99.102.209
91.99.102.213
91.99.102.233
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address);
```

Answer (score 2):

For your case, this should work:

```
SELECT ip_addr_str
FROM mytable
ORDER BY inet_aton(ip_addr_str)
```